# Python: subclasses with the same sets of methods v.s. multiple dispatches

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, polymorphism

I was writing a class with the set of methods that work as expected for both numpy arrays and scipy.sparse matrices. I then realized that all my methods starts with an if-statement to check if the underlying matrix is dense or sparse e.g.

```
def standardize_columns(self):
    if self.issparse():
        …
    else:
        …

def multiply_by_diagonal_matrix(self, diag_vector, from_='right'):
    if self.issparse():
        …
    else:
        …
```

It seems somewhat silly (and not pythonic) to have such if-else statements everywhere. I have so far found two possible ways around this: 1. create an abstract class with pre-specified set of methods and make subclasses (https://pythonspot.com/polymorphism/, https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), or 2. create a set of functions with multiple dispatch (https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch).

Which of the two approach (or any other) would be better and why?

Comment: looks that you want to create a `SparseMatrix` subclass to override default behaviour

Comment: I want the methods to work equally well with dense matrices as well.

Comment: What do you do when `self.issparse()` returns False? Is it another version of the function or it is a similar thing in each method?

Comment: Another version of the function. The output of methods are meant to be mathematically identical whether `self.issparse() == True` or not, but is represented differently internally depending on whether the underlying matrix is dense or sparse.

Comment: Other than this `if/else` is there anything in common between these 2 functions (and the others)?  Any common pattern, something that can be generalized across all functions.

Comment: There are very little in common; making a unified class would make sense if there were more in common, but the codes that can be shared between dense and sparse matrix cases are so small (maybe 10%) that it seems logical to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a long comment than an answer.

- subclassing `numpy.ndarray` is not a trivial undertaking.
- scipy.sparse formats are already implemented as classes - several different ones; none are subclasses of `ndarray`.
- the behavior of sparse matrices is modeled on `numpy.matrix` subclass - always 2d, * is matrix multiplication.
- `numpy` functions work on sparse matrices ok, IF, they delegate the action of a method.  In other words, if there are identically named sparse and dense methods, you can often get by with that method or a function that uses it.  This the Python duck-typing.
- scikit-learn has a lot of code that accepts both sparse and dense.  It may be worth looking at how it handles that.  I know they have added some utility code, including some faster `cython` stuff to speed up selected sparse actions.
- sparse.linalg has a concept of linear operator, which just requires that the object have a particular matrix*vector` multiplication.
- when you do things with sparse matrices, make sure you understand what is produced.  Sometimes the sparse format changes.  Sometimes the result is a `np.matrix`, or `np.ndarray`.

Without more details of your functions, it will be hard to suggest a more systematic approach.